# Any downside to switching to 2" thick air filter?

Tags: furnace, air-filter

I've been using 1"-thick Filterbuy pleated MERV 8 filters for one of my furnace air intakes (it has two). I realized recently that a 2"-thick filter would fit in there.

I think that using a 2"-thick filter instead of the 1" will be easier on the system (easier to move the air), as long as I use the same filter (Filterbuy MERV 8), since the filter's surface area will be larger. Are my thoughts correct?

Comment: We moved up to 4" and never looked back. If the tenants aren't going to change them then they need to last longer than one month.

Answer (score 1):

You're right.  A 2" filter has more surface area, so it's going to be less restrictive and allow more airflow.

The other commenter was incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

A thicker filter will let less air through at the same pressure. How much difference that makes depends on your specific setup

Comment: But is my air filter thicker if it's the same material as before, just with pleats that are two inches high instead of one inch (and so more surface area of the same material)?

Comment: Are you certain it's the same material? Could be  thicker. Though if there's more surface area from the deeper folds that should offset it somewhat.